# Select data from another table with where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

What's wrong with this query, im selecting data from 3 different tables here. First title of exam from "class_exams" table , second selecting sum of total marks from "results" table. Query works fine without where clause.

```
SELECT id, exam_date , (
SELECT title
FROM class_exams
WHERE result_heads.exam_id = class_exams.id
) AS exam_title, (
SELECT sum( marks )
FROM results
WHERE result_heads.id = results.head_id
) AS obt_marks

FROM `result_heads` WHERE exam_title = 'test';
```

Error comes

```
Unknown column 'exam_title' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Join

If I understand the table schema , it should be like this :

```
SELECT result_heads.id, result_heads.exam_date , sum( results.marks )AS obt_marks
FROM results JOIN result_heads
     ON results.exam_id = result_heads.id
GROUP BY result_heads.id, result_heads.exam_date
```

Comment: it works but still `class_exams` table is missing from your query, actually i need to display `title` field of `class_exams` as well on matching `exam_id` field which is in `result_heads` table.

Comment: please add you table schema and what is the expected result so I can adjust the query. you can add join on that table will solve your question ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the name of table in where clouse

```
WHERE `tbl_name`.`exam_title = 'test';
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is an old post, but I like to fill the answers where old posts end to prevent dead end posting.  It looks like the table name is not being called out in the From clause

See this link http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/where.php and look at the example - Joining Tables.

Comment: Please add the examples to your questions without 3rd party site links with examples.